# How to get the screen shot of the window on mac?

Tags: io

I am trying the take the screen shot of the window in mac. I can either take the screen shot of all screen or none. But i only want to take the screen shot of window. Any help appreciated

Comment: [http://www.ninisworld.com/thecorner/tutorials/osxscreenshots.html](http://www.ninisworld.com/thecorner/tutorials/osxscreenshots.html)

Comment: This is the wrong place to ask that question. check out http://www.superuser.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use Command + shift + 4, and you will get a crosshair. After you have outlines what is in the screenshot, press the space bar to capture. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

=> Cmd+Shift+4+space

=> Cmd+cntrl+Shift+4+space

4 means portion

4+space will select window portion

Cntrl direct to copy to clipboard

Use combination with ur wish